# Clear datagrid values in wpf

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, datagrid

I need to flush my `datagrid` everytime when a `treeviewitem` is clicked. My code is given below.

```
private void treeView1_SelectedItemChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<object> e)
{
    this.dataGrid1.Columns.Clear();
    this.dataGrid1.ItemsSource= null;
    String path =this.treeView1.SelectedItem;
    if (!File.Exists(path))
        MessageBox.Show("Not Found");
    else
    {
        ob.provider(path);

        //   String data = @"C:\logs.xml";
        string data = path;
        objref.functionality(data);
        this.dataGrid1.ItemsSource = objref.Result;
    }
}
```

But everytime when I click a treeview item datagrid is not cleared-- it's appended with incoming data. 
I used both `dataGrid1.Columns.Clear()` and `dataGrid.ItemSource= null;`
How can i do this??

Answer (score 33):

If you are populating the DataGrid by using:

```
dataGrid.Items.Add(someObject);
```

Then you should be able to use:

```
dataGrid.Items.Clear();
```

To remove all the rows.

If you are binding to the ItemsSource like:

```
dataGrid.ItemsSource = someCollection;
```

Then you should be able to set the ItemsSource to null and it will remove all the rows.

EDIT:

Don't forget to refresh it:

```
dataGrid.Items.Refresh();
```

Comment: Am populating with ItemsSource. i already set it to null. That was my question. But my datagrid still not cleared..

Comment: Is that the only location you are populating it?

Comment: try refreshing it: dataGrid.Items.Refresh();

Answer (score 4):

You may consider using `ObservableCollection<>` class rather than `IEnumerable<>`.

```
ObservableCollection<User> users = new ObservableCollection<User>();
dataGrid1.ItemsSource = users;
```

You can clear the datagrid by using the below code.

```
users.Clear();
```

Answer (score 4):

I have tried several approaches and this was by far the best and most reliable one:

```
dataGrid.Columns.Clear();
dataGrid.Items.Clear();
dataGrid.Items.Refresh();
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a public `IEnumerable` collection which is appended every time the function is called. So by overwriting it, I flushed the Data in my Datagrid.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to clear my Data-Grid by setting the DataContext to null.

```
DataGrid.DataContext=null;
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is bound an Itemsource, the simplest way is

`dataGrid1.ItemSource = null;`

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve this using the following:

```
DataGrid.ItemsSource = null;
DataGrid.Items.Clear();
```