# How to clear datagrid items in wpf while having button in column of each row

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I want to delete datagrid items in wpf.

I have tried

```
 dataGridfix.Items.Clear();
 dataGridfix.Items.Refresh();
 dataGridfix.ItemsSource = null;
```

but due to having button in each row , it stops to clear datagrid.

can u suggest good idea?

full code is here

```
   private void showfix() 
   {
         dataGridfix.ItemsSource = null;
         DataTable dt = new DataTable();
         dt.Columns.Add("ID");
         dt.Columns.Add("Account");

         SqlDataAdapter msadapt = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from fdetails  order by fdid desc", mscon);
         DataTable msdata = new DataTable();
         msadapt.Fill(msdata);

         for (int i = 0; i < msdata.Rows.Count; i++) 
         {
             string id = msdata.Rows[i].ItemArray[0].ToString();
             string acc = msdata.Rows[i].ItemArray[2].ToString();
             dt.Rows.Add(id, acc);
         }

         dataGridfix.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
         dataGridfix.Columns[0].Width = 50;
         dataGridfix.Columns[1].Width = 50;
         dataGridfix.Columns[2].Width = 180;
     }
```

xaml code is

```
                                <DataGridTemplateColumn >
                                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate >
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <Button Name="btndelfix" Click="btndelfix_Click" >Delete</Button>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                            </DataGrid.Columns>
```

Comment: Could you post the xaml code? or a screenshot on the situation of failed clean?

Comment: post your `DataGrid` XAML, we should know how your buttons are added to `DataGrid` i suppose you should have a `DetaTemplate` for placing the button.

Comment: yes you are right Abin. I have data templete for placing the button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried doing `dataGridfix.ItemsSource = null` then doing 
`dataGridfix.Items.Refresh()` instead of the other way around [as seen here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14473171/4587181)?
You need to clear the itemsSource property for the binding to stop working. Then nothing should block you from emptying the datagrid.
To me the DataTemplate using a button is not related to your problem.